# Is there a way to optimize a code that checks if a string matches the value of each column?

Tags: java

Im using these technologies in my project, grails, java and hibernate.
Now, I'm creating the backend for listing entries from db and there is an option to search. The search is not specific to a column, meaning, If I typed, "MB102" it is possible that this will match an address or an employee code.

Now, the thing is I have 20+ columns to check per entry and that would mean 20+ ladder ifs

```
if (employee.birthDate.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
    searchEmployeeList.add(employee);
    continue;
} else if (employee.civilStatus.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
    searchEmployeeList.add(employee);
    continue;
} else if (employee.civilStatus.toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
   searchEmployeeList.add(employee);
   continue;
}
```

I just want to know if there is a way to shorten this kind of process? I'm not lazy, I just want to know if there is already an existing function to make our lives easier. Thank you.

Comment: You could call toLowerCase() once, You could also build an index of `Map<String, List<Employee>>` which returns all the employees which match a word for any reason.

Comment: Most of the solutions I am imagining will use reflection, which could be a performance problem if you are working on large sets of data (and if not implemented correctly)

Comment: Matching the same input against 20+ alternative columns doesn't sound very user-friendly, because the result set will contain lots of noise (false positives) with certain inputs. Anyways, you could do this with plain-old SQL and let the DB worry about caching etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This answer is aimed for the "purpose" of the question, and not the technical question itself. **It is showing how to significantly speed-up the entire search, and not for a specific employee**.

You can build a [suffix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) of all the records of all employees - and let the reference to the relevant `Employee` object be stored in a leaf of each suffix.

When a query is given, you can follow the query string from the root, if there is some node that matches the query (there is a suffix that starts with the query string) - it means, all leaves of the tree, which are reachable from this node - are matches.

Do some graph search algorithm (BFS or DFS) from this node, and collect all employees in the leaves.

This will give you significantly better performance to collect all employees when their number rises.